# vslam: where is the file " current.rtc"?

Tags: ros, vslam-system, vslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to run vslam on my own datasets, but it can not find the current.rtc.
I checked the 'data' folder, no current.rtc inside.
However, my stereo data runs smoothly on the ROS:vslam using the original setting file "stereo_vslam.launch".

My question is what the current.rtc is? How could I find it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11065/vslam:-where-is-the-file-%22-current.rtc%22?/) by [GuoliangLiu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1015/guoliangliu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2011-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just in case some newbies have the same problem: the "current.rtc" comes from the other package "calonder_descriptor", so the solution is simple: install this package from the source.

---

Originally posted by [GuoliangLiu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1015/guoliangliu/) with karma: 36 on 2011-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-08-31**:
@tfoote or @mwise_wg, can we get a force accept on this one?